# How does the Diode work from MorphVOX Pro?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, audacity, soundeffect, audioeffect

I'm trying to construct a audio modifier including the diode from MorphVOX. I can't match this effect with any other effect I found on other programs, and there is no documentation on this effect.

Here is a audio example of what the diode does on Diode mode with max intensity.

Without Diode: https://clyp.it/rhfxaozv

With Diode: https://clyp.it/uhpdnaie

How is this effect created, and how do you recreate it in audacity?